# Charts with proper unicode support

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, charts, cairoplot

I want to create simple charts like pies and bars in python.

I tried out `CairoPlot` and `pycha`. Both look amazing, but they seem not to be able to handle unicode characters properly.

```
CairoPlot.pie_plot(name='test.png', width=800, height=600, 
                   data={'eins':100, 'zwei':48, 'drei':90, 'vier':98,u'fünf':187})
```

result in `fÃ¼nf` instead of `fünf`.

Is there an easy to use module with proven support for unicode? or did you make `CairoPlot` or `pycha` display the unicodes correctly?

I prefer in-house solution, so google chart is not what I want.

**edit**

ironfroggy's answer made me try this

```
CairoPlot.pie_plot(name='test.png', width=800, height=600, 
                   data={'eins':100, 'zwei':48, 'drei':90, 'vier':98,'f\xc3\xbcnf':187})
```

this works.

What is a safe way to convert unicode-strings to ascii-strings with escaped non-ascii characters?

**edit 2**

```
u'fünf'.encode('latin-1')
```

does the trick. Thanks!

**edit 3**

for pycha it worked in the same way

```
dataSet = (                                
     ('dataSet 1', ((0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2.5))),
     ('dataSet 2', ((0, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3))),
     (u'dataSet Ü'.encode('latin-1'), ((0, 5), (1, 1), (2, 0.5))),
)
chart = pycha.bar.VerticalBarChart(surface)
chart.addDataset(dataSet)                  
chart.render()
surface.write_to_png('output.png')
```

Comment: If unicode strings don't work, it's a bug in the module you are using, you should report it. If they really require latin-1 encoded strings, they should document that really well as well.

Comment: I openend a Ticket earlier this day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful including non-ASCII directly in your source. Are you including an encoding hint in your source?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

And, of course, are you sure your editor is properly saving the file in the encoding you think it is? The safest bet is still to keep source in ASCII and to do unicode string literals with escaped non-ASCII characters (like \UXXXX where XXXX is your codepoint).

Comment: The unicode-strings come from a mysql-table. please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a third party library to replace the garbage unicode , i will be happy to provide you with a one upon professional consulation